# How to set boolean value to a JSP variable and validate it in a .tag class

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, jsp-tags

I want to add an inactive icon in front of each single option of a drop down list if it is not active. Im using a select.tag class and .jsp class.

This is the related snippet code for .jsp

```
<div id="reviewCategoryChoice">
                        <iTag:select path="reviewCategoryBeans" basicSelect="true"
                        isActive= "${deactivationDate == null}"
                        cssClass="selectpicker"  label="Choose a service to modify"
                        required="true" defaultEmptyOption="Choose a service"
                        labelWidthClass="col-xs-4"
                        inputWidthClass="col-xs-7"
                        items="${reviewCategories}"
                        itemLabel="deactivationDate"
                        itemValue="id" />
```

This is the related snippet code for select.tag

```
<c:when test="${not empty items and empty nestedItems}">
               <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">     
                            <option value="${item[itemValue]}"
                                    <c:if test="${(not empty defaultValue) && (defaultValue == item[itemValue])}"> selected="selected"</c:if>
                                <c:if test="${isActive eq false}"> class="icon-mrs-is-inactive" </c:if>>
                                     ${item[itemLabel]}
                            </option>
                </c:forEach>
</c:when>
```

Even though this won't give an error, the condition won't satisfy. I want to make sure whether these `isActive= "${deactivationDate == null}"` line in .jsp class and `<c:if test="${isActive eq false}"> class="icon-mrs-is-inactive" </c:if>>` line in .tag class are correct or wrong.
Thank You in advance.